# Rotation matrix with OpenGL 4

Tags: c++, c, opengl, matrix

I'm trying to rotate a triangle with OpenGL 4 using matrixes, but the triangle appears to reverse direction when halfway. It's obviously not rotating directions, so I must have the depth buffer wrong somewhere. I've tried resolving this but I haven't found any examples of a rotation with OpenGL 4, only ones that use depreciated functions. Here is my code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "maths_funcs.h"
#include "maths_funcs.cpp"

const char* vertex_shader =
"#version 400\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertex_position;"
"layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertex_colour;"
"uniform mat4 pmatrix;"
"uniform mat4 rmatrix;"
"uniform mat4 smatrix;"
"out vec3 colour;"
"void main () {"
"  colour = vertex_colour;"
"  gl_Position = smatrix * rmatrix * vec4 (vertex_position, 1.0);"
"}";

const char* fragment_shader =
"#version 400\n"
"in vec3 colour;"
"out vec4 frag_colour;"
"void main () {"
"  frag_colour = vec4 (colour, 1.0);"
"}";

float angle = 0.0f;

int main () {
    // start GL context and O/S window using the GLFW helper library
    if (!glfwInit ()) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not start GLFW3\n");
        return 1;
    } 

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow (640, 480, "Triangle Rotation test", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: could not open window with GLFW3\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent (window);

    // start GLEW extension handler
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit ();

    // get version info
    const GLubyte* renderer = glGetString (GL_RENDERER); // get renderer string
    const GLubyte* version = glGetString (GL_VERSION); // version as a string
    printf ("Renderer: %s\n", renderer);
    printf ("OpenGL version supported %s\n", version);

    // tell GL to only draw onto a pixel if the shape is closer to the viewer
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth-testing
    glDepthFunc (GL_LESS); // depth-testing interprets a smaller value as "closer"

    float points[] = {
        0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
    };

    float colours[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f
    };

    float pmatrix[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    float rmatrix[] = {
        cos(10), 0.0f, sin(10), 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
        -sin(10), 0.0f, cos(10), 0.0f, 
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    float smatrix[] = {
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, cos(10), sin(10), 0.0f, 
        0.0f, -sin(10), cos(10), 0.0f, 
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    GLuint vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers (1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof (float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    unsigned int colours_vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers (1, &colours_vbo);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colours_vbo);
    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof (float), colours, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays (1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray (vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colours_vbo);
    glVertexAttribPointer (1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader (vs);
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader (fs);

    GLuint shader_programme = glCreateProgram ();
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
    glLinkProgram (shader_programme);

    int pmatrix_location = glGetUniformLocation (shader_programme, "pmatrix");
    int rmatrix_location = glGetUniformLocation (shader_programme, "rmatrix");
    int smatrix_location = glGetUniformLocation (shader_programme, "smatrix");

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose (window)) {
        // wipe the drawing surface clear
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram (shader_programme);
        rmatrix[0] = cos(angle);
        rmatrix[2] = sin(angle);
        rmatrix[8] = -sin(angle);
        rmatrix[10] = cos(angle);

        smatrix[5] = cos(angle);
        smatrix[6] = sin(angle);
        smatrix[9] = -sin(angle);
        smatrix[10] = cos(angle);
        glUniformMatrix4fv (pmatrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, pmatrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv (rmatrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, rmatrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv (smatrix_location, 1, GL_FALSE, smatrix);
        glBindVertexArray (vao);
        // draw points 0-3 from the currently bound VAO with current in-use shader
        glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        // update other events like input handling 
        glfwPollEvents ();
        // put the stuff we've been drawing onto the display
        glfwSwapBuffers (window);

        angle+=0.01f;
        if (angle >= 3.14f) {
            angle = -3.14f;
        }
    }

    // close GL context and any other GLFW resources
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not sound like it has anything to do with your depth buffer... you do, however, appear to be applying scale and rotation in the wrong order in your vertex shader. *assuming that is what s and r are supposed to stand for?*

Comment: Well, r is rotation and s is another rotation matrix. If I only use one of them the triangle still appears to switch direction halfway.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out shortly after, just by looking at what the matrices contained. Those names kind of bug me ;) I assumed **s** was uber-shorthand for scale, **r** for rotation and **p** for projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using a projection matrix, you have to invert the z-coordinate in your vertex shader. Change this line:

```
gl_Position = smatrix * rmatrix * vec4 (vertex_position, 1.0);
```

To something like this:

```
vec4 eyePos = smatrix * rmatrix * vec4 (vertex_position, 1.0);
gl_Position = vec4(eyePos.xy, -eyePos.z, eyePos.w);
```

The `gl_Position` value is in clip coordinates, which after the division by `w` results in NDC (normalized device coordinates). While world coordinates are typically specified in a right-handed coordinate system, with the z-axis pointing out of the screen, NDC is a **left-handed** coordinate system, with the z-axis pointing **into** the screen.

Typical projection transformations take care of flipping the z-coordinates from out-of-screen to into-screen. But if you're not using a projection transformation, you have to flip the z-coordinate yourself.

Also, you may want to double check that you really got a depth buffer. Maybe add this before `glfwCreateWindow()`:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DEPTH_BITS, 24);
```

Based on what I could find in the GLFW documentation, this is probably the default. But it couldn't hurt to specify it explicitly.